# How can I make jupyter not depend on any conda env?

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, miniconda

I installed miniconda, compact version of Anaconda, and then run 
`conda install jupyter`
to install jupyter notebook since it doesn't come with Miniconda.
Then, I created another env. It seems I need to install jupyter again at that env.

Does it mean I download it twice?? or internal conda only have 1 copy of jupyter?
How can I make jupyter not depend on any conda env? Should I install by pip instead?

Thanks!

Comment: This seems off-topic under "Questions about ... general software".

Answer (score 0):

For each conda environment you should do an ipython kernel installation as described [here](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install/kernel_install.html). When you have done so, the next time you open jupyter from the default (root) environment you will have the option to use and/or change to any kernel (environment) you want, without having to explicitly call jupyter from that environment.